# Custom Exception Handling in WEB API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using WEBAPI 2 has my backend for my App.I am using custom exception handling with help of some good blog,Now what i am using its working good,But i need to display my custom message which i am passing in my custom exception need help below is my code!

```
public class GlobalException: System.Web.Http.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionHandler
{

    public override void Handle(ExceptionHandlerContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is ArgumentNullException)
        {
            var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            {
             //Here i am getting some different value in message and in ParamName its give my custom message,How to access the ParamName rather then context.Exception.Message
                Content = new StringContent(context.Exception.Message),
                ReasonPhrase = "ArgumentNullException"
            };

            context.Result = new ArgumentNullResult(context.Request, result);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public class ArgumentNullResult : IHttpActionResult
    {
        private HttpRequestMessage _request;
        private HttpResponseMessage _httpResponseMessage;


        public ArgumentNullResult(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage)
        {
            _request = request;
            _httpResponseMessage = httpResponseMessage;
        }

        public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(_httpResponseMessage);
        }
    }



 }

   //Controller Method in WEBAPI//
   public IHttpActionResult Sendmessage()
    {
       //here i am send null value with my custom message
      throw new ArgumentNullException("Test Null Value");
    }
```

Comment: What is the source of you custom message? In general you can just use custom exception that encapsulates any parameter you want to send.

Comment: "throw new ArgumentNullException("Test Null Value");" this my custom message string

Comment: So is it correct that you want to return new StringContent("Test Null Value")? Do you prefer to pass this value in some other way than context.Exception.Message? Or do you get some other value in context.Exception.Message and not "Test Null Value"?

Comment: yes!, i am getting this value:"Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: Test Value Cant be null" in context.Exception.Message

Comment: are you saying you want return only your custom message in error response...??

Comment: Replace ArgumentNullException with Exception. ArgumentNullException assumes you provide parameter name and formats message accordingly

Comment: @vivek, yes i need to return only custom message

Comment: @Igor,thanks it works,I replaced ArgumentNullException with Exception

Comment: @nagaraj - follow Igor advice and replace ArgumentNullException with Exception then you will get only your custom error message.

Comment: @vivek thanks, it working  for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to return "Test Null Value" as a content instead of "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: Test Value Cant be null" you shoud use either usual Exception or custom exception if you need to have different behavior.

You can't use ArgumentNullException that expects parameter name and formats message accordingly

Comment: so in  ArgumentNullException i cant send my custom message,I need to know

Comment: You can (there is a constructor with 2 parameters) but you should not in general. It's main purpose is to report about missing parameter. If you want to process exception of this type you'd better use ((ArgumentNullException)context.Exception).ParamName. If you want just to distinguish your special exception I'd use custom exception type